# Apache2 could not bind to (arbitrary) address, and unable to open logs

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I currently have other services listening on port 80, and so I've configured apache to listen on port 444 which definitely has no services listening on it.

However, when I attempt to start apache, I receive this error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:444
```

Have also tried (and failed) to bind to `0.0.0.0:444`. The error after this is:

```
Unable to open logs
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

Regarding user:

```
# envvars
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
APACHE_RUN_GROUP=root

$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data root

$ ls -l /var/log/apache2
total 60
-rw-r----- 1 www-data root     0 May  9 08:02 access.log
..other files, same permissions..
```

As explained above, there is nothing listening on 444:

```
netstat -anp | grep 444
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57444           0.0.0.0:*                           761/avahi-daemon: r
```

Comment: Two things, - since the port is < 1024, you need priviledge user to bind to it. Are you launching Apache as root? You can check what is listening on the port with `netstat -anp | grep 444`

Comment: sounds about right. unable to open th elog files probably means you're trying to run as non-root and apache can't open the root-only default /var/log/... dir+files

Comment: Thanks, I've updated with more information. It appears I'm running as root (user within root group) and there 100% nothing listening on port 444.

Comment: Well if you can't access the logs and you can't bind to the port, I wonder if another  instance of apache is already running.

Answer (score 0):

try changing port to 4444 or something bigger than 1024 and see if apache can started. You can try delete all log files, except directory. 
also you can check if log file is not open `lsof | grep /var/log/apache2`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't access the logs and you can't bind to the port, I wonder if another  instance of apache is already running. Have you run:
 `ps aux|grep httpd` 
after the errors are reported to make sure that there is not another apache instance that is running on the server? 
I mean something is blocking the same two resources you want - sounds like it might be another copy of what you are running.

Also you could use lsof to see what is using those resources:

```
lsof |egrep access\.log\|444
```

Boom!